# Capturing a WPF user control's data in a property when used as a template

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I've run into a spot of trouble with my research. I'm relatively new to WPF and any of its practices, perhaps I'm attempting something I should not... at any rate, I cannot find a solution for my problem so I shall ask.

I've created a simple WPF application to act as a notification box. The window displayed has a `ListBox` that contains these notifications. I've decided to use a `user-control` to template these notifications and add needed functionality to each one. example, the ability to complete, acknowledge or ignore.

I've been able to get these notifications to display just fine, my problem however is creating a proper binding to access the entirety of the custom `NotificationObject` down the road (as it is the application that handles that logic as opposed the the user control itself).

What I have is as follows.

The window has a `ListBox` defined as such:

```
<ListBox Name="NotificaitonContainer" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource NotificationTemplate}"/>
```

The `ItemSource` is set int the back end with: `NotificaitonContainer.ItemsSource = notificationList;`

The template is defined as:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="NotificationTemplate">         
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5,5,5,5">
        <uc:Notification CompleteClicked="CompleteTask" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

The `user-control` is defined as:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Notification_WPF.Windows.Components.Notification"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" Height="50" Width="400" Background="#FFACA4A4">
<Grid>
    <Label Content="{Binding Path=name}" />
    <Button Name="completeBtn" Content="complete" Click="completeBtn_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

With the code behind defined as:

```
public partial class Notification : UserControl{
    NotificationObject note;

    public event EventHandler CompleteClicked;

    public Notification() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void completeBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        ((Panel)this.Parent).Children.Remove(this);

        if (CompleteClicked != null) {
            CompleteClicked(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

}
```

now, the problem I am having is seting the `note` object when using this pattern of binding. I wish to pass the `note` object through my `CompleteClicked` event handler so that I may have proper reference to the notification being completed. But I don't know how to capture the `NotificationObject` when the notification is being created.

Does anyone know how to capture the data object being bound and store that on a parameter?

**EDIT**

Due to my personal confusion, I'm adding this section to create clarity of my intentions. 
What I am trying to accomplish is a desktop tray application that periodically pulls from a custom task management web app and notifies users of the status of given tasks assigned to them within a finite time frame.

The tray app portion of my app is running fine, however in it I have created an event that runs on a timer which is handled as:

```
private void TimerHandeler(object sender, EventArgs e) {            
        List<NotificationObject> NotifyList = getNotificationList();

        if (notificationBox.Visibility == Visibility.Visible) {
            notificationBox.Display(NotifyList);
        } else {
            notificationBox.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Render, null);
        }
    }
```

the `notificationBox` is in essence my `MainWindow` and contains the `ListBox` I'm working with as shown above.

To display it I have the code behind as:

```
public void Display(List<NotificationObject> notifications) {
        var desktop = SystemParameters.WorkArea;
        this.Left = desktop.Right - this.Width - 15;
        this.Top = desktop.Bottom - this.Height - 15;
        this.Focus();

        buildTaskList(notifications);

        this.Show();
}

private void buildTaskList(List<NotificationObject> notifications) {
    //this is how I did this before... which is apparently incorrect.
    this.notificationList = notifications;
    NotificaitonContainer.ItemsSource = this.notificationList;
}
```

And the new `NotificatonList` I'm told should be the `MainViewModel` and looks like:

```
class NotificationList : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private ObservableCollection<NotificationObject> _noteList;
    public ObservableCollection<NotificationObject> NoteList { 
        get { return _noteList; }
        set {
            _noteList = value;
            onListChange();
        } 
    }

    private void onListChange() {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

        if (handler != null) {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(null));
        }
    }
}
```

I hope I put that together right...

Now what I want to do, is click a notification in the list box of `notificationBox` and update the web app. how might I go about approaching this?

Comment: could the down voter please clarify why they voted as such? Am I going about WPF all wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not how you'd do it at all. The "right way" is a little weird but it's actually less annoying, once you get a handle on it.

Some of these, it may be doing already. Let me know if you need more detail on any particular point.

1. You need a main viewmodel that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.
2. `MainViewModel` exposes a public property `ObservableCollection<NotificationObject> Notes { get {...} set {...} }`, which raises `PropertyChanged` in the `set`.
3. `MainViewModel` is responsible for populating `Notes`. It should never know or care who's looking at `Notes`. That's beyond the scope of its responsibilities.
4. Use your viewmodel:

   ```
   public MainWindow()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       DataContext = new MainViewModel();
   }
   ```
5. Bind the viewmodel's `Notes` property to `ListBox.ItemsSource` in the main view XAML. No need to do it programatically. Better, in fact, if you don't. Now it will listen to `PropertyChanged` and update the listbox if you assign a new collection to `Notes`. The theme with MVVM is you set properties on the viewmodel, and things magically (*magically*, I tell you) happen in the UI.

   ```
   <ListBox
       ItemsSource="{Binding Notes}"
       >
       <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
               <!-- 
               Notification no longer has the CompleteClicked event.

               Notification.DataContext will be the NotificationObject for this 
               ListBox item. You're already using that fact to bind the name property. 
               -->
               <uc:Notification />
           </DataTemplate>
       </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
   </ListBox>
   ```
6. `NotificationObject` should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` as well.
7. `NotificationObject` gets an `IsCompleted` property, and raises a `Completed` event when `IsCompleted` becomes true. Alternatively, you could have an `IsCompletedChanged` event that raises when `IsCompleted` goes from false to true or vice versa.

   ```
   private bool _isCompleted = false;
   public bool IsCompleted { 
       get { return _isCompleted; }
       set {
           if (_isCompleted != value)
           {
               _isCompleted = value;
               if (_isCompleted)
                   OnCompleted();
               OnPropertyChanged();
           }
       }
   }

   //  Purists may argue that an event handler's "args" parameter should always 
   //  inherit from EventArgs, and they may be right, but it's no capital crime. 
   public event EventHandler<NotificationObject> Completed;

   private void OnCompleted() {
       if (Completed != null) {
           Completed(this, this);
       }
   }
   ```

   `MainViewModel`'s handler for that one:

   ```
   void note_Completed(object sender, NotificationObject note)
   {
       Notes.Remove(note);
   }
   ```

   It sets that up when it creates the `NotificationObject` instances and populates `Notes` with them. Instead, you could lose this event, and `MainViewModel` could also just handle `PropertyChanged` on the `NotificationObject`s that it creates. It's a matter of taste; I prefer this way.

   Or it might be better, instead, to simply filter the items shown in the ListBox by `IsCompleted`, depending on your requirements. Then `MainViewModel` would refresh the filter when any `NotificationObject` changes its `IsCompleted` state.
8. In the view, there's no `CompletedClicked` event and no private `note` property. Instead, it just tells its `Note` that it's complete. The consequences of that are none of the view's business. That's all between the viewmodels.

   ```
   private void completeBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
       ((NotificationObject)DataContext).IsCompleted = true;
   }
   ```

   Or skip the click event and use a toggle button:

   ```
   <ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding IsCompleted}" Content="Complete" />
   ```

   When the user clicks it, it sets `IsCompleted` to true. Done. When you find your codebehind shrinking down to nothing but a constructor, or when you find that your usercontrol could just be a plain `DataTemplate` with no code, that's a sign that you're doing MVVM right.

You're probably reading this and your eyes are spinning counterclockwise. If so, that's understandable. Here's the thing: It's actually not that bad once you get used to it, and it puts you in a place where you just set up a bunch of stuff, link it together declaratively, and for the most part *it just works*.

Comment: phew... your right about my eyes spinning.... As I've been trying to get this to work I'm not seeing how I populate the new Notes collection... how do I access that?

Comment: You would populate it in `MainViewModel`'s constructor, probably. Where are the notes coming from? The rule with viewmodels is the viewmodels *are* the program, so to speak: They own the data, they talk to each other. The views are just sort of ornaments hung on the branches, displaying stuff for the user and getting input.

Comment: Ok, allow me to refine my question.  At various points of the apps lifespan this list of Notes will change.  how do I then change the collection of Notes at a point beyond the initialization? Or should I be creating a new instance of this window every time it is displayed?

Comment: You change the Notes collection by adding and removing items. The `ObservableCollection` automatically tells the `ListBox` what happened, and the `ListBox` magically updates. It just works. If you implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` properly on `MainViewModel`, `MainViewModel` can just say `Notes = new ObservableCollection<NotificationObject>();`  and the `ListBox` will magically repopulate in that case as well.

Comment: Ok, we are getting closer to my answer.  The disconnect I am having is not between `Notes` and `ListBox`, but rather between some behind the scene event that collects the new list of things to display and updating `Notes` with this new list. With `Notes` sitting on the `DataContext` how to I then access it? something like `DataContext.Notes` does not work....

Comment: @NealByington Of course it's not magic, it's just that the `Binding` class knows about the interfaces `INotifyPropertyChanged` (for your viewmodel), and list controls know about `INotifyCollectionChanged` (which `ObservableCollection` implements for you), and they have a lot of code to monitor what your code is doing via those events, and update accordingly.

Comment: @NealByington The nerve center of the application is MainViewModel; that's who drives things. That's "where you are", as the programmer, when you think about how to make things happen. That's who updates `Notes`. If you want to update `Notes` every 30 seconds, the `MainViewModel` should create a `BackgroundWorker` that does that. If you want the user to tell you to update `Notes`, you'd give `MainViewModel` a `Command` property that does that, and then your view would bind it to a Button's Command property, or a MenuItem's Command property, or whatever.

Comment: `DataContext` is how view accesses *you*, not how you access viewmodel. You *are* viewmodel. The view's codebehind may, however, cast `DataContext` to whatever viewmodel type (e.g. `((NotificationObject)DataContext).IsCompleted = true;` in the usercontrol click handler in my answer)

Comment: Hmm... with this approach I feel like I'm moving farther from my goal line.... Allow me time to update the OP and add clarity for the whole scope of what I am attempting....

Comment: @NealByington Can you clarify the relationship between KarmaNotification and NotificationObject? My guess is it's KarmaNotification in your actual project, and you've been calling it NotificationObject in your question to avoid confusion, but wanted to be sure.

Comment: @NealByington Rather than toss fragments at you, I just threw my version together and put it on Dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/s/809nq3v7i5n56n3/Notifications-00.zip?dl=0

Comment: @NealByington I don't know how you're doing the task tray stuff so I just ignored that part. Shouldn't be much trouble to merge in your code for that part. I also made some other assumptions, but it's full of longwinded rambling comments that hopefully clarify my thinking, or will at least bore you into not caring what I think.

Comment: Wow, this is quite helpful. Thank you for taking the time to do this. I'll get back to you once I've had time to digest it.

Comment: Ok, I've got everything adapted and working but this: `public ViewModels.NotificationObject ViewModel => (ViewModels.NotificationObject)DataContext;`
I've had to adjust due to difference in C# versions... but I can't figure out what this is doing? is it a simple casting or is there more to it?

Comment: @NealByington Yeah, it's just identical to `{ get { return (ViewModels.NotificationObject)DataContext; } }`. The point is just to eliminate having to clog up the code with `((ViewModels.NotificationObject)DataContext)` everywhere.

Comment: Sweet! Thank you for your help, I've managed to get what I needed done. You have been a great help, both in guiding me through my project and learning WPF.